# Install app in Windows docker which runs multiple services

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, service, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize an application which runs multiple services when installed and if the connection to the central server has been seen from one of these services, it will download and install additional services.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 22
WORKDIR /
COPY WindowsProbeSetup.exe /
COPY Wait-Service.ps1 /
RUN echo "1.1.1.1 some.url.ext" >> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts && ping some.url.ext
ARG PROBETYPE=Local_Windows
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
Run Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "./WindowsProbeSetup.exe" -ArgumentList @('/quiet', '/v" /LV c:\install.log /qn CUSTOMERID=xxx CUSTOMERSPECIFIC=1 REGISTRATION_TOKEN=some_guid_string SERVERPROTOCOL=HTTPS SERVERADDRESS=some.url.ext SERVERPORT=443 "')
RUN Get-Content -Path c:\install.log
RUN Get-Service
CMD powershell.exe -file c:\Wait-Service.ps1 -ServiceName 'Windows Software Probe Maintenance Service' -AllowServiceRestart
```

The problem is that i can't retrieve the logfile install.log to see what went wrong. Or am i doing something else wrong.
The Exe is a wrapped MSI installer. (got this from the software supplier).

> Some data in the codesnippet has been altered for privacy, that's why I use 1.1.1.1 and some.url.ext and also xxx and some_guid_string.

Comment: Use "CMD /K powershell.exe" which keeps the command window open after script finished.